# Can command handlers be separated from aggregate roots in CQRS

Tags: domain-driven-design, domain-model, cqrs, event-sourcing

On one hand, the invariants should be protected (To make invalid states impossible early and preferably at compile time rather than run time), and on the other hand, passing domain knowledge out of the domain is wrong.

On one hand, the value objects protect our domain invariants at first place, on the other hand using them as commands or as it's properties equals passing domain knowledge around.

The only solution for both protecting the invariants, and avoiding the domain knowledge from leaking the domain boundary (encapsulating the domain model), seems to **wrap the aggregates in a command-to-value-object-mapper**.

I'm using CQRS along with ES.

Is it ok to have a wrapper as a *command-to-value-object-mapper* around my aggregate roots? Is there any other solution?

Comment: "the value objects protect our domain invariants at first place" : what do you mean? Invariants are primarily protected by aggregate roots, not VO's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> On one hand, the value objects protect our domain invariants at first
>   place, on the other hand using them as commands or as it's properties
>   equals passing domain knowledge around.

Nothing in DDD says that you shouldn't pass domain knowledge around. Quite the contrary - the Ubiquitous Language means that domain knowledge will be everywhere from front end to repositories.

You might mean domain **logic** instead.

Commands don't include domain logic. They are dumb data structures that *describe* user intention and the data associated. They don't *implement* anything. So if you use commands properly, you're good to go - no domain logic leakage.

Comment: You seem like have not gotten the main question. Let me change its title to make it clearer.

Comment: Now I'm confused. The new title mentions command handlers while the question body does not. And your title is in the affirmative form. Interrogative form would be more appropriate.

Comment: Thx. I fixed the form, the question would be sth like: `Can command handlers be separated from aggregate roots and value objects be composed at the command handlers in CQRS?` but it would be too long. And the body is supporting it. Find the phrase: `wrap the aggregates in a command-to-value-object-mapper` from the page.

Comment: Sorry, I can't make any sense of that question except that you're making a big big confusion between Commands, Command Handlers and Value Objects.

Comment: In addition to a big confusion between knowledge and logic.

Comment: I mean I don't like to pass the commands to my aggregates.I'd like to pass the value objects to aggregates, and the only way to do that is to separate the command handlers from the aggregate root, and I'm asking whether it is ok to do that or not.

Comment: Maybe. Thank you for making it clear, and sorry if the question was not clear enough.

Comment: What implementation are you referring to where command handlers are merged with aggregate roots? Most of the time they aren't. They have different names for a reason. Do you have a link to sample code?

Comment: Better, can you include sample code for what you mean in your Q?

Comment: Yes. An implementation I could search and find fast is this one:  http://cqrs.nu/tutorial/cs/02-domain-logic

Comment: So is it ok to create value objects at command handlers and pass them to aggregates?

Comment: Sample implementations by two of the biggest names in DDD, [Young](https://github.com/gregoryyoung/m-r/blob/master/SimpleCQRS/CommandHandlers.cs) and [Vernon](https://github.com/VaughnVernon/IDDD_Samples/blob/05d95572f2ad6b85357b216d7d617b27359a360d/iddd_agilepm/src/main/java/com/saasovation/agilepm/application/product/ProductApplicationService.java), have separate handler classes. (the latter is called Application Service but it's the same, it takes Commands as inputs)

Comment: **But** the reason has nothing to do with Value Objects. It's because Command handlers might have other, *applicative* responsibilities - initiating / Concluding a business transaction, logging, etc.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80537/discussion-between-guillaume31-and-mohsen).

Answer (score 1):

> On one hand, the value objects protect our domain invariants at first place, on the other hand using them as commands or as it's properties equals passing domain knowledge around.

I do not agree with this. You may do whatever you need with your Commands and Events, even store them if you like. They are immutable and do not contain domain knowledge. They represent the intent and the fact.

Passing around domain knowledge could mean to have the domain code/logic spread around in layers other than the domain, i.e. in Application or Infrastructure services, which is indeed bad.

The solution is to keep the domain code that handles invariants (the domain logic) inside the Aggregates (this includes the Aggregate root, the nested Entities and the Value objects). BTW, you may pass around the Value objects also, as arguments to method calls; they are also immutable, as an indication that modifying them is not allowed or is pointless.

> Is it ok to have a wrapper as a command-to-value-object-mapper around my aggregate roots? Is there any other solution?

No, it is pointless.  Also, transforming them into something else would make them to loose the *intent*, their most important aspect.

Comment: Commands are messages kind of like immutable DTOs ,but value objects are objects. Objects defined as data+ behaviour.

Comment: @Mohsen Commands have data and behavior: they contain basic validation like non-null checking or minimum or maximum value checking.

Comment: Take a look at this(the first answer only): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4869473/value-objects-in-cqrs-where-to-use

Comment: @Mohsen I read it. My answer stands.

Comment: The value objects are rich domain behaviour representative, and the only thing I find in them that is same as commands is their immutability. Sometimes yau may use the value objct api like a builder which build itself step by step, but since you should be able to stor the commands, and the behaviour is not serializable ...

Comment: Since the creation of value objects and their API is mapped to ubiquitous language, it's a domain model. Value onjects also may include other value objects and composing them at other layers equals exposing the domain knwoladge to other layers. This is my theory, I'm just trying to understand your point, correct me if I'm wrong. Thx.

Comment: @Mohsen validation behavior is still behavior. And sometime Value objects do not have so rich behavior as you may think. Sometimes all they bring is only high cohesion between some properties, at least at the begining. Passing Commands and Events around keeps the things simple and reduces the accidental complexity. With a good framework you could have only the Domain layer and a little infrastructure. The framework would unserialize commands directly from a HTTP body and Events from the Event store.

Comment: @Mohsen look at http://cqrs.nu .they send commands directly to an Aggregate. I like and use a lot this style.

Comment: Yes, I've seen it, and I can see what you mean, but I just don't like to miss those nice value object composition which represents the language by composing it's words through the API.

Comment: @Mohsen I see. I see no real harm in separating  the Commands from the Value objects but my answer still stands: do not map Commands to something else, just let them reach their goal, to express an intend to modify an Aggregate's state. A command is part of an Aggregate's API and it may reach it.

Comment: And I find that more domain centric and cleaner aggregate.

Comment: Thabk you. Nice discussion.